# MVC wrong view/model being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I´ve a mvc4 application which is working fine on regular scenario.

However, under the scenario I´ll describe I´m getting the following bug:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
softWrench.sW4.Web.Models.LoginHandler.LoginHandlerModel', but this dictionary
requires a model item of type 'softWrench.sW4.Web.Models.Home.HomeModel'.
```

**to reproduce it (only on FF or IE)**

1. Login to the application (which calls the LoginController and LoginModel, then does a immediate redirect to HomeController/HomeModel)
2. Hit the backspace/back button --> the user returns to login page
3. Try to login again with the wrong username/password pair. Under
   normal circunstances that would just bring a error message on
   screen, but here I get the exception.

It seems to me that, for some reason the mvc is invoking the Index.cstml of the HomeController, and not the `IndexController` one...

On Chrome, however, when I hit the backspace I get auto-redirected to the `HomeController`, instead of the login page, so there´s no way to reproduce it. The reason is that, apparently chrome does an extra server request to LoginController when the backspace is hit, and that simply doesnt happen on FF and IE; Since the user is still authenticated, I´m redirecting him to the HomeController on that extra request; If FF and IE, did that request on the backspace I would be ok with it as well...

I reinforce that the app is running fine, except for this backspace scenario, so there doesn´t seem to be any gross mistakes like typos or wrong models being called on the code.

I debugged the scenario but couldn´t find any thing so far, the HomeController isnt called, just the LoginController and this should be redirecting to the Index.cshtml of it....

Comment: Please put your controller and view code related to it? It will help us to solve the problem easily

Comment: Hi @Aravandian could fix it in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I could fix it. It was kinda hard to describe it completely here, and for that I´m sorry.

I forgot to mention that I had an overriden impl of RazorViewEngine, which was checking for the user not being authenticated to return a empty razor template.

In the scenario I described, however, the user was still authenticated and, hence, it was returning the wrong razor template instead of null. That razor template (Layout.cshtml), was the culpright for asking the wrong model.

I did an extra checking for the ViewPath containing SignIn to also return null and that covered that extra case.

Answer (score 2):

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type softWrench.sW4.Web.Models.LoginHandler.LoginHandlerModel, but this dictionary requires a model item of type softWrench.sW4.Web.Models.Home.HomeModel.

This error simply means your passing `LoginHandlerModel` when it requires `HomeModel`. There is mismatch between passing model to **view** and `strongly type` bind **view**

Comment: Yes, you were right, it was just a little bit harder to catch the case here. Thanks